# appending anything but a string to std::stringstream returns 0

Tags: c++, stringstream, integer-division

Code in question:

```
        std::stringstream cd;
        int f = int((15 / allyCounter) * 100);
        cd << f;
```

allyCounter is equal to 45. the idea is to get what percentage 15 is of allyCounter where allyCounter is a dynamic int that is constantly changing. i don't have much experience with c++ so I'm sure what I'm missing is something fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is almost certainly with integer vs. floating point math.

15/45 (when done in integer math) is 0.

Try

```
    std::stringstream cd;
    int f = int((15.0 / allyCounter) * 100);
    cd << f;
```

...and see if things aren't better. 15.0 is a double precision floating point constant, so that'll force the math to be done in floating point instead of integers, so you'll get a percentage.

Another possibility would be to do the multiplication ahead of the division:

```
int f = 1500 / allyCounter;
```

If the numerator were a variable, this could lead to a problem from the numerator overflowing, but in this case we know it's a value that can't overflow.

Comment: thanks. not too familiar with c++ and i was using a map iterator so I wasn't sure if iterator->second would return my defined type of int or not.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `15 / 45` is `0`. (It's called "integer division": the result of dividing two `int`s in C++ is also an `int`, and thus the real answer is truncated, and `15 / 45` is `0`.)

If this is your issue, just make it a double before doing the division:

```
int f = static_cast<double>(15) / allyCounter * 100;
```

or even:

```
int f = 15. / allyCounter * 100;
```

(The `.` in `15.` causes that to be a double.)

Comment: Yes, `allyCounter` is an integer "...where allyCounter is a dynamic int that is constantly changing."

Comment: @PlasmaPower: Ah thanks, missed that part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer division:

```
std::stringstream cd;
int f = int((15.0 / allyCounter) * 100);
cd << f;
```

The compiler sees `15/allyCounter` and thinks it should return an integer (you passed it two integers, right?). `15/150 == 0` with integer division, you always round down. In this case the compiler sees `15.0` as a double, and uses decimal places.